# Amplifier Repair - How can I find a replacement transformer?

Tags: amplifier, audio, transformer, repair, fault

So I'm trying to repair an old Marantz 1040M amplifier, which after being run at high volumes on New Year's(!!) no longer powers on :(

My electronics knowledge is fairly rudimentary, but I think I have identified the problem as being transformer related. The primary winding reads an open circuit on a multimeter, and there is no voltage across any of the secondary terminals when a voltage is applied to the primary.

[image: tranny]

It has three primary terminals (0v, 210v and 240v for EU/UK use) and four secondary taps.

I want to replace the transformer, however I can find no information online regarding its specifications. Searching for the part number yields zero useful search results.

Some research has revealed that the 1040M is internally identical to the PM-200. I have found the relevant service manual, but that shows little clues as to the transformer specs -

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/691537/Marantz-Pm200.html?page=8#manual

I have contacted Marantz, who say that the company has changed hands so they have no access to specifications of older products! Both of the repair companies Marantz pointed me to are of no help either.

The label on the transformer reads -

TS1662002-0
(ETP66P2E)

and to the side of that -

6931M

So basically the question is, can I repair this amp, or should I sell it for spares and write the whole thing off?

Is there a way of somehow figuring out what voltages the board needs, just using a multimeter? Could I even crack the transformer open and repair the coil? I'm fairly sure the secondary winding is okay. Any advice much appreciated.

Cheers,

Oli

Comment: Tricky. The middle terminals in the secondary have double wires. I wonder what that means.

Comment: @PkP: It very likely means they are center taps.

Comment: There are companies out there that offer a transformer rewind service

Comment: There are actually plenty of clues in the schematic, but the low-resolution scan makes them hard to read. The main clue is that the main DC buses are labeled +32V and -32V, which implies that the transformer secondary windings are about 24Vrms. There's a small extra winding attached to the end of one of the windings, but the purpose of this is not entirely clear, since it is half-wave rectified and regulated down to about 20V. I suspect that it has something to do with providing a "soft start", but it seems to me that the regulator input could just as well be tied directly to the +32V rail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes transformers have a thermal fuse underneath the black tape wrapped around the coils.  You could carefully remove the tape and replace the thermal fuse if there is one.  For example - http://www.electronicrepairguide.com/images/thermalfuseinside.jpg

Comment: You beautiful man! I found a blown thermal fuse hiding under that tape. Should be an easy fix to get power flowing back through this old beast, let's hope nothing else is broken... thank you!

https://imgur.com/a/ONh4P

Answer (score 2):

If the main power leads are no longer connected (you wrote, "the primary winding reads an open circuit on a multimeter") you will have to find where the wire break is located within the transformer and repair it. I don't think there's any escaping that but you might get lucky and find that the break is very near one lead or the other. If not, dismantling that transformer may be difficult. (But what is the worst thing that can happen? It breaks. And you are no worse off.)

But before you go and throw it out or attempt to tear apart the transformer you can do something else, first. You already know the AC mains voltage. So that's good. What you need to do is to find out the AC secondary winding voltages. Assuming those are still working okay, you can go find a 6.3 VAC transformer and wire up its secondary to any of two wires that are still connected (test with an ohmmeter to work out all the leads that appear connected to each other.) [If you can find a lower AC voltage secondary than 6.3 VAC then use that instead. Up to a point, lower is less risky when testing like this.] You can then measure the voltages at other pairs and, from that, work out the likely secondary voltages on the transformer.

If you do this and work out the required secondary voltages (through such testing) and already know the mains voltage, as well, then you can go look up a replacement. (You'll need to find one that weighs about the same, or more, though.) Or just find several such transformers, if you can't find one that matches up the same on all of the secondary voltages.

I'm not sure what else to suggest right now. But it's late here. If something else comes to mind, I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

Some transformer winding Houses offer a  ' Detail Rewind service '  where they strip the core out and wind exactly the same windings with the same number of turns and wire sizes .This can cost a little more and may be worth it .Otherwise you can look at the big electro caps and multiply the volts by say .7 and use lab supplies to slowly crank up the volts checking current .You can now see if your amp still goes .If it does then its time to replace the power transformer .

Comment: Good idea about the transformer repair house. But a scary idea about about looking at the cap voltages... I once put a 100 volt cap to the USB voltage, as one happened to be lying around. Trying that unit with 70 volts would have set it off in flames!